# What is the stat 'Fumble'?

Tags: torchlight-2

I couldn't get a very clear explanation over the internet. Within the Dexterity stat figures "Fumble Recovery"

[image: fumble]

What does it mean if the attack is "fumbled"?

Comment: Fumbled Attacks = Chance of your attack dealing less damage

Comment: Fumbled Recovery = Reduces the damage penalty for Fumbled Attacks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in most RPGs there are critical hits. A fumbled attack in Torchlight II is a critical hit with negative impacts. By pressing <kbd>J</kbd> you open your `Arcane Statistics` (by default):

[image: arcane statistics]

This character has a `21%` chance to hit a negative critical strike. This hit would deal only `-49%` of the normal damage.

By skilling `DEX` you reduce this rate. With e.g. the `+30% Fumble Recovery` from your screenshot, my character would have a malus in dealt damage of only `-19%`when he does a fumbled attack, however the `Fumble Chance` keeps the same.

Comment: So if I score a critical strike, there's a chance to fumble that critical strike, which means.. dealing less critical damage than intended?

Comment: A fumbled critical hit will do the fumble damage, not the critical damage.